# How do I build a canvas line graph between 2 varying dates?

Tags: graph, html5-canvas, linegraph

I'm trying to use canvas to build a line graph between 2 date points.  I need the date measurements along the bottom of the graph to change based on the start and end date data, which can vary widely between what information is grabbed by the application.  Are there any plugins that do this, specifically/dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge abundance of chart and graph plotting libraries that can do this, and [gRaphaël](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) seems to do what you ask for quite well.